# Get rid of IF statements by using functors

Tags: c++, if-statement, functor

please teach me how to get rid of those if statements by using functors (or any other better methods) inside the following loop:

```
//Loop over each atom
std::string temp_name ; 
float dst;
for (pdb::pdb_vector:: size_type i=0; i < data.size(); ++i)
{

    if (type == 0) 
    {
        //choose by residue name
        temp_name = data[i].residue_name;
    } else {
        //choose by atom name
        temp_name = data[i].atom_name;
    }
    //compare the name and extract position if matched
    if (temp_name.compare(name) == 0) 
    {
        if (direction.compare("x") == 0)
        {
            dst = ::atof(data[i].x_coord.c_str());              
        } else if ((direction.compare("y") == 0)) {
            dst = ::atof(data[i].y_coord.c_str());                  
        } else {                
            dst = ::atof(data[i].z_coord.c_str());  
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this question?

Comment: Why not `if (temp_name == name)`?

Comment: My purpose is to get rid of "if (type ==)" and "if (direction.)" statement by using functor or any other methods. The above loop is inside a function call. Depends on what "type" and what "direction " as input parameters, the function perform the same calculations on different vars.

Comment: @Khoa given that C++ is mostly imperative, unless you can do compile-time checks you have to do runtime checks (if-else).

Comment: If you store direction as an int or enum and the coords as an array, you could use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `if(type == 0)` with the ternary operator:

```
// if(type == 0) ...
temp_name = (type == 0 ? data[i].residue_name : data[i].atom_name);
```

but the rest of your checks seem like they would only be less readable if you tried something similar.